# Error when accessing synonyms in python using nltk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I have written a very simple piece of code to try and print the synonyms associated with a word.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wordNetSynset =  wn.synsets('small')
for synSet in wordNetSynset:
    for synWords in synSet.lemma_names:
        synonymList.add(synWords)
print synonymList
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for synWords in synSet.lemma_names:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you please add the python version and `nltk` version?

Comment: Sure. It's Python 2.7.6 and for nltk, it's '3.0.2'.

Comment: Cool got the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nltk 3, the `lemma_names` has been changed to a method from an attribute.

So you have to call the method

```
for synWords in synSet.lemma_names():
```

Other minor changes required are:

- `synonymList` is not defined
- List will not have an `add` method even if `synonymList` is defined
- You better name your variable `synonymSet`

Comment: @Jess Nice. I was waiting for you to mention Nltk 3!